# How to deal with bad_alloc in RAII?

Tags: raii, bad-alloc

The code is as follows:

```
class A;
shared_ptr<A> aPtr(new A());
//do something with aPtr.
```

If new throws a bad_alloc exception, what happend to the smart point aPtr? Do I need to do some check with aPtr, and how to do? And I know one of the Google C++ program rules is never using exceptions, but how they deal with exceptions like bad_alloc? Thank you for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a `bad_alloc` you're pretty much screwed anyway. I'm not sure how you expect to handle the allocation failing here. Not using exceptions does not really apply in this case.

If you *really* want to opt out of it you can add a `nothrow` to that statement and it'll return `nullptr` instead of throwing a `bad_alloc`:

```
shared_ptr<A> aPtr(new (std::nothrow) A());
```

For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277637/new-stdnothrow-vs-new-within-a-try-catch-block) about the design consideration involved. Additionally see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4718116/1348195) explainign why using `std::nothrow` is a bad idea.